# Simplifying big O notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Hey i have done some practice questions simplifying bigO expressions, can someone check which ones are right and which ones aren't?

I'm quite new to this

[image]

i) O(n^3)

ii) O(n^3)

iii) O(log(n))

iv) O(n^5/2) ?????

v)  O(n^2)

[image]

i) O(n^2)

ii) O(n^2)

iii) O(3^n)

iv) O(2^n)

v) O(n^3)

[image]

i) O(n)

ii) O(n)

iii) O(n^2)

iv) O(n^2)

Answer (score 3):

In the first group, your (ii) is wrong, it should be **O(n<sup>2.3</sup>*log(n))**.
The rest in that group are correct.

In the second group,

(ii) should be **O(x)**,

(iv) should be **O(n*2<sup>n</sup>)**, and

(v) should be **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**.

The rest in this group are correct, except that I'm not sure if you're supposed to keep the original `x` or `m`, or else replace them with `n` as you did.

In the third group, all of your answers are correct.

Comment: Can (n^3.2*log(n)) not be simplified further by losing the decimal in the exponent?

Comment: @Minvy No, BigO polynomial powers are real numbers, not just integers.  So n^2 is less than n^2.1 which is less than 2.11, and so on...

Comment: @Evg, I think that it goes like this, `O(n 2^(n+1)` => `O(n 2^n)` => `O(2^(log2(n)) * 2^n)` => `O(2^(n+log2(n)))` => `O(2^n)`.  I'm pretty sure that last step is correct, for the same reason that `2^(n+1)` reduces to `2^n`.

Comment: @Evg, hmmm, I did the formal check and you are right.  I will correct my answer...

Comment: @Evg Heh, right again.  I read the associativity wrong.  Obviously `(x+2*x+3)` is *not* `(x+2)*(x+3)`.  I can't believe I read that one wrong.

Comment: @Evg thx.  I had no idea I was going to have to work so hard on this answer ...